# Where can I download the Spring DM jar files?

Tags: spring, osgi, spring-dm

Actually I was reading about Spring Dynamic Modules and OSGi. All of them referenced the URL http://www.springsource.org/osgi for downloading the related libraries and jar files.

As you can verify, everytime I click on this url, it gives me the following error page:

> [image]

So I was searching for an alternative and then find the **manning** forum which can be found here https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/25280.page
and in this forum they answered:

> go to this page: http://www.springsource.org/download

Finally when I click on the last link it is being redirected to the **http://spring.io/projects** site, in which there is no sign of Spring DM.

My Question is How/Where can I download the latest version of Spring DM libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring DM is discontinued for a long time now.

It is replaced by blueprint now which is an OSGi standard. There are two implementations [Apache Aries Blueprint](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) and [Eclipse Gemini Blueprint](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/).

Remember though that blueprint is not fully compatible to spring. For example you can not easily use the spring namespaces. On the other hand blueprint is much better adapted to OSGi than spring DM which causes a lot of classloading problems.

For selecting between the two implementations I suggest to go with the one that matches you runtime environment. If you plan to do server side work then you should consider [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org). It is very well integrated with Apache Aries but not so well with Gemini. On the other hand if you choose Eclipse virgo as a server then Eclipse Gemini Blueprint is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the project was moved to Eclipse, it is now called Eclispe Gemini Blueprint (http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/ - also has links to the Download page), I'm not so sure if that project is alive either.

From http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/eclipse-migration.html:

> Chapter 1. Spring Dynamic Modules becomes Eclipse Gemini Blueprint
>
> In late 2009, as a member of the Gemini project proposal, SpringSource
>   contributed Spring Dynamic Modules (also known as Spring OSGi) project
>   to the Eclipse Foundation. Spring DM v2 code base has been moved to
>   Eclipse.org along with its issue tracker and forum. The project became
>   dual licensed under Apache License and EPL. While the name has
>   changed, the code and its functionality remained the same. Existing
>   Spring DM applications can be easily migrated to Eclipse Gemini
>   Blueprint as mentioned in the migration guide. While the project name
>   has changed (to Eclipse Gemini Blueprint) and significant efforts have
>   been made to reflect this in the project documentation and resources,
>   there might be places that we have missed; if you find any, please
>   report them to us.